# $.post() and appendTo not working in firefox?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to append table tbody using `appendTo` inside a `$.post()`.

It works in chrome, but it in firefox it is not working.

Anyone can help me?

here is my code:

```
$.post('categories_content.php','',function(data) {
  $.each(data,function(i,data) {
    //do something
  });
  $(myvar).appendTo("table tbody");
},'json');
```

Comment: can you show the code that you're using?

Comment: I fixed my mistakes in my code. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Please format the code clearly. You do realise the code which you are trying to append is outside the callback function and as of now you are trying to append code before the call back even happens.

I have no clue wat is happening in Chrome but looking at your function it should be

```
$.post('categories_content.php', '', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, data) { //do something 
        $(myvar).appendTo("table tbody");
    }),
    'json'
});
```

let me know if I got your question correctly.